# Get emojis from message discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to get first emoji from message on discord.js

example: `<message>.content.emojis.first()`

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just recently had this issue as well! The solutions I was able to put together were these:

TL;DR
You wanna use `.includes` for simply finding if an emoji is present in a message
Here's a small example:

```
    const message = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
    let findEmoji = message.includes("<:")
    let firstEmoji = findEmoji.first()
```

End of TL;DR.

Here's a very long and drawn out version that can grab an emoji and spit back out an embedded image using RegEx:

```js
  const hasEmoteRegex = /<a?:.+:\d+>/gm
  const emoteRegex = /<:.+:(\d+)>/gm
  const animatedEmoteRegex = /<a:.+:(\d+)>/gm

  const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
  const message = messages.find(m => m.content.match(hasEmoteRegex))

  if (emoji = emoteRegex.exec(message)) {
  const url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/" + emoji[1] + ".png?v=1"
  msg.channel.send(url)
  }
  else if (emoji = animatedEmoteRegex.exec(message)) {
  const url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/" + emoji[1] + ".gif?v=1"
  msg.channel.send(url)
  }
  else {
  message.channel.send("Couldn't find an emoji to paste!")
  }
```

This uses RegEx to filter out the different parts of an emoji as a string.
A standard emoji would look like: `<:emojiname:emojiID>` eg. `<:BBwave:562730391362994178>`
An animated emoji would look like: `<a:emojiname:emojiID>`

The RegEx takes each of these parts and splits them up into

```
<
:BBwave:
562730391362994178
>
```

or

```
a
<
:BBwave:
562730391362994178
>
```

The code that I supplied basically takes *just* the ID and does away with all of the other info. It then adds this ID into a standard emoji link for Discord: https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/562730391362994178.png?v=1 or into an URL that has `.gif` at the end for animated emoji.

I hope this isn't too overwhelming! I know that it certainly was when I first started using discord.js.

Answer (score 1):

The current response doesn't recognize the possible escape case, and ignores unicode emojis, so I have implemented matching those into the regex.

```js
const EMOJIREGEX = /((?<!\\)<:[^:]+:(\d+)>)|\p{Emoji_Presentation}|\p{Extended_Pictographic}/gmu;

var emojis = "test my emojis <:test:954125076455190109>   ".match(EMOJIREGEX);

console.log(emojis);
```

Prints:

```
[ '<:test:954125076455190109>', '', '', '' ]
```